# JS code for web template only working for full control user

Tags: content-search-web-part, web-template

I deployed the control list with paging and item template for using the with Content Search Web Parts, we have realized that users with no Full Control are not able to run the logic in these templates. SP admin has told me that this is not correct because the users won't be configured with Full Control, so my question is, what else should be configured in order to get the scripts running? My understanding is that all the users that have access to the folder will be able to run the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in most cases they should be able to, unless running scripts has been disabled by an admin or they do not have access to the place where you placed the script file. Because the file has been published, right?

Comment: Yes, the files have been published, and the users have access (Read) to the location but the issue remains unless they are Full Control which is not allowed by SP Admin. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a self service created site, as per https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000188451-prerequisite-1-enabling-scripting-capabilities?

Comment: I'm working with SP 2013 on-premises I think this does not apply to this version, do you know if there is any similar feature in 2013?

Comment: You have tested it in different browser? Does the Chrome dev tools show anything?

Comment: Same behavior in IE and Chrome, no errors in the console for dev tools, I have been debugging the code through the Dev tools and the code is reachable (I can show alerts or console.log) but just not doing the change on values per code, it is odd.